# Strange behavior for event handler

Tags: httprequest, dart

New to Dart.

I am developing a simple Dart program simulating the legacy Guess Animal program: the user thinks of an animal, the program tries to guess it by asking Y/N questions.

I have developed my backend using Symfony with some simple RESTful interfaces, and it works fine in browser. I am now using Dart to develop the frontend. The code is shown below.

Phenomenon:

1. Clicking the "New" button works fine. getNextQuestion(questionId) got called correctly and getNextQuestionComplete also correctly showed the question and choices of answers (Y/N).
2. Clicking the YES link and the getNextQuestion() called with the right question ID but the req object's status is 0, instead of 200.

Any hints?

Rgds!

Taylor

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';

int questionId;
int yBranch;
int nBranch;

void main()
{
  init();
}

void init()
{
  // Hook up event handlers
  querySelector("#btnNew").onClick.listen(newGame);

  querySelector('#y').onClick.listen(getYBranch);
  querySelector('#n').onClick.listen(getNBranch);
}



void getYBranch(Event e)
{
  getNextQuestion(yBranch);
}

void getNBranch(Event e)
{
  getNextQuestion(nBranch);
}

void newGame(Event e)
{
  questionId=1;
  yBranch=-1;
  nBranch=-1;

  querySelector("#lblProgress").text="Game in progress...";
  querySelector('#gamearea').style.display="block";
  querySelector('#answerlinks').style.display="block";


  //Get Root Question
  getNextQuestion(questionId);
}

String getNextQuestion(questionId)
{
  var path='http://rsywx/app_dev.php/animal/getQuestionByID/$questionId';
  var req=new HttpRequest();
  req..open('GET', path)..onLoadEnd.listen((e)=>getNextQuestionComplete(req,    questionId))..send('');
}



void getNextQuestionComplete(HttpRequest req, qid)
{
  if(req.status==200)
  {
    Map res=JSON.decode(req.responseText);
    querySelector('#question').innerHtml=res['q'];
    querySelector('#qid').innerHtml=qid.toString();

    yBranch=res['y'];
    nBranch=res['n'];

  }

  req=null;
}
```

Comment: Did you verify the request reaches the server script? response code 0 typically is a very lowlevel error, without involvement of the HTTP protocol - for example, "no internet connection", "server not found" etc.

Comment: @MarioP Yes, I did. Basically, the path I am visiting when I click "YES" is the same as the very first time the program starts. Copying the path value out when debugging and put it in the browser and it can return the desired result. And actually "rsywx" is on my local machine so connection should not be an issue.

Comment: Decided to re-write this with Dart/Polymer, seems promising.